# Finding the maximum distance from the starting node

Tags: python, time-limit-exceeded, graph, complexity

I've tried everything to make my program faster but with 250 nodes my code takes around 9 seconds to print the result, and with 5000 nodes it took around 260 seconds.

Is there a way to make my program faster?

I took the BFS function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753257/can-this-breadth-first-search-be-made-faster).

> The site(connections) should consist of three towns each of which is connected to
>   directly the other one by a road. The distance between two towns A and
>   B is the minimum number of pairs of directly connected towns on the
>   way from A to B. Two towns are connected directly by a road R if there
>   is no other town on R between A and B. The distance of any possible
>   site from the capital city is equal to the sum of the distances from
>   each of the three towns representing the site from the capital city.

Output: the maximum possible distance of a site from the capital city, the number of all sites which are located at the maximum distance from the capital city.

[image]

> there are two most distant sites from the capital in node 9, the sites
>   are {0, 1, 3} and {2, 3, 5} and their distance from the capital is 10

Input first line (nodes_count, pairs_number, capital)
Next all the pairs

Input

```
10 17 9
0 1
0 3
1 3
1 4
2 3
3 4
2 5
3 5
3 6
4 6
4 7
5 6
6 7
6 8
7 8
7 9
8 9
```

Output

```
10 2
```

My code

```
from collections import defaultdict
from queue import Queue


def read_nodes(pairs_number):
    for _ in range(pairs_number):
        yield map(int, input().split())        


def parse_input(tree):
    nodes_count, pairs_number, capital = map(int, input().split())
    for node1, node2 in read_nodes(pairs_number):
        tree[node1].append(node2)
        tree[node2].append(node1)
    return tree, capital, nodes_count


def traverse_path(fromNode, toNode, nodes):
    def getNeighbours(current, nodes):
        return nodes[current] if current in nodes else []

    def make_path(toNode, graph):
        result = []
        while 'Root' != toNode:
            result.append(toNode)
            toNode = graph[toNode]
        result.reverse()
        return result

    q = Queue()
    q.put(fromNode)
    graph = {fromNode: 'Root'}

    while not q.empty():
        current = q.get()
        for neighbor in getNeighbours(current, nodes):
            if neighbor not in graph:
                graph[neighbor] = current
                q.put(neighbor)
        if current == toNode:
            return make_path(toNode, graph)
    return []


def distant_sites(graph_dic, capital, nodes_count):
    distance_with_connections = defaultdict(list)
    node_distance = {}
    for towns in range(nodes_count):
            towns_distance = len(traverse_path(capital, towns, graph_dic)) - 1
            node_distance[towns] = (towns_distance)
    for town1, neighbours in graph_dic.items():
        for town2 in neighbours:
            if town1 > town2:
                for neighbour_of_town2 in graph_dic[town2]:
                    if town2 > neighbour_of_town2:
                        if neighbour_of_town2 in neighbours:
                            town_connection = (town1, town2, neighbour_of_town2)
                            distance = (node_distance[town1]) + (node_distance[town2]) + (node_distance[neighbour_of_town2])
                            distance_with_connections[distance].append(town_connection)
    max_distance = max(distance_with_connections)
    return max_distance, len(distance_with_connections[max_distance]) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    graph_dic, capital, nodes_count = parse_input(defaultdict(list))
    max_distance, number_of_connections = distance_sites(graph_dic, capital, nodes_count)
    print(max_distance, number_of_connections)
```

Comment: So you consider all non-capital cities, and for each of them you compute the **maximum** possible distance to the capital, is it correct?

Comment: Yes and they should form a connection of three towns , also the number of sites(connections) in the maximum possible distance to the capital

Comment: I am not quite sure about your algorithm, yet, in general, searching for longest path [is NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem), which implies that there is no exact polytime algorithm for it unless \$P = NP\$.

Comment: yeah but I'm also searching for all the possible connections between the towns(three towns), The site(connections) should consist of three towns each of which is connected to directly the other one by a road.

Comment: and my implementation there takes more time

Comment: @Joe: I rolled back your edit because I answered the question based on your original code, and it would be confusing to have an answer which does not match the question.

Comment: @coderodde: The question is not asking for the *longest* path. It's asking for the most distant triangle, where the distance of a triangle is  the sum of the distances of its three nodes, and the distance of a node is the *shortest* path from the origin to that node.

Comment: @GarethRees Ah, got it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The code does not work because of a typo — there is a call to `distance_sites` but there is no such function.
2. There are no docstrings. What do these functions do? How do I call them?
3. In order to improve the performance, we need to measure it, and in order to do that, it's helpful to be able to make test cases of arbitrary sizes. So let's write a test case generator:

   ```
   from itertools import product

   def test_case(n):
       """Construct a graph with n**2 nodes and O(n**2) triangles, and return
       a tuple (graph, capital, number of nodes).

       """
       graph = defaultdict(list)
       for i, j in product(range(n), repeat=2):
           k = i * n + j
           if i < n - 1:
               graph[k].append(k + n)
               graph[k + n].append(k)
           if j < n - 1:
               graph[k].append(k + 1)
               graph[k + 1].append(k)
           if i < n - 1 and j < n - 1:
               graph[k].append(k + n + 1)
               graph[k + n + 1].append(k)
       return graph, 0, n * n
   ```

   Then we can easily measure the performance of the code using [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit):

   ```
   >>> from timeit import timeit
   >>> timeit(lambda:distant_sites(*test_case(50)), number=1)
   51.7171316598542
   ```

   with \$n=50\$ the graph has 2,500 nodes and 4,802 triangles.
4. [`queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue) is a thread-safe data structure intended for use by multi-threaded programs. It has to take and release a lock for every operation, so it is overkill to use this in a single-threaded program. It is more than ten times faster to use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead:

   ```
   >>> timeit(lambda:distant_sites(*test_case(50)), number=1)
   4.451224883086979
   ```
5. The code computes the distance from the capital to each town by running a separate breadth-first search for each town. But this repeats a lot of work: in the course of finding the distance to town A, the breadth-first search will have to visit towns B, C, D, and so on. It would make sense to remember the distance to each town as we visit it, and so compute the distances from the capital to *all* the towns in one go:

   ```
   from collections import deque

   def distances(graph, origin):
       """Return a dictionary mapping each node in graph to its distance from
       the origin.

       """
       result = {origin: 0}
       visited = set([origin])
       queue = deque([origin])
       while queue:
           node = queue.popleft()
           distance = result[node] + 1
           for neighbour in graph[node]:
               if neighbour not in visited:
                   result[neighbour] = distance
                   visited.add(neighbour)
                   queue.append(neighbour)
       return result
   ```

   This gives a couple of orders of magnitude speedup on the test case:

   ```
   >>> timeit(lambda:distant_sites(*test_case(50)), number=1)
   0.030185375828295946
   ```
6. The code for finding the most distant sites looks at all triangles. But this likely involves a lot of wasted effort. For example, suppose we find a triangle whose nodes have distance 48, 49 and 50 from the origin (with sum 147). Now there is no need to look at any triangle unless it contains a node with distance \${147\over 3} = 49\$ or more. So if we sort the nodes in reverse order by their distance from the origin and just remember the best-scoring site, then we may not have to consider very many sites before we know that we have found the most distant one.

   ```
   def distant_sites(graph, origin):
       """Return the pair (max_site_dist, site_count), where max_site_dist is
       the maximum distance of any site in the graph from the origin, and
       site_count is the number of sites at that distance. A "site" is a
       triangle of nodes, and its distance from the origin is the sum of
       the distances of the three nodes.

       """
       distance = distances(graph, origin)
       nodes = sorted(((d, n) for n, d in distance.items()), reverse=True)
       max_site_dist = 0
       site_count = 0
       for dist1, node1 in nodes:
           if dist1 * 3 < max_site_dist:
               break
           neighbours = graph[node1]
           for node2 in neighbours:
               dist2 = distance[node2]
               if (dist2, node2) >= (dist1, node1):
                   continue
               for node3 in graph[node2]:
                   if node3 not in neighbours:
                       continue
                   dist3 = distance[node3]
                   if (dist3, node3) >= (dist2, node2):
                       continue
                   site_dist = dist1 + dist2 + dist3
                   if site_dist > max_site_dist:
                       max_site_dist = site_dist
                       site_count = 1
                   elif site_dist == max_site_dist:
                       site_count += 1
       return max_site_dist, site_count
   ```

   The speedup you get from this optimization depends on the kinds of graph you feed it (if there are few sites then it won't make much difference). For my test case we get about 40% speedup:

   ```
   >>> timeit(lambda:distant_sites(*test_case(50)), number=1)
   0.017997111193835735
   ```